# How to check if a combobox is checked

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a problem because I wanna know if this what I did in a asp-classic is checked or not

```
td class="auto-style16"><nobr><b>
        <% if p_chk_disponivel <> "" or p_num_sala = 0 then %>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkDisponivel" checked>Somente Disponiveis</input>
      <%else %>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkDisponivel">Somente Disponiveis</input>
      <%end if %>
  </b></nobr></td>
```

I tried getElementsByname but don't worked, can someone help me the funcition that I was using is that.

```
var dis = document.getElementsByName("chkDisponivel")
if(dis.checked){
    alert('Checked')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByName()` returns a collections ,use `[]` to access individual elements.

`document.getElementsByName("chkDisponivel")[0]`

Comment: Isn't worked, I insert [0] inside the if and like you said, mine application just stopped and doesn't worked

Comment: "I insert [0] inside the if ", not inside if i meant `var dis = document.getElementsByName("chkDisponivel")[0];`

Comment: Ahh, I was thinking like a array, I was checking the position [0]. But now I Understood, thank you :)